# Refactoring .asmx file in Visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, visual-studio-2012

I have created my first ASP web service in Visual Studio 2012, for which the code now looks like this (this is the file `TestService.asmx.cs`):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace MyWS
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://something.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class WS1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do now is to rename the class `WS1` into something more informative, say, `HelloWorldService`. For that, I assumed that Visual Studio's refactoring capabilities should be more than sufficient, so i selected `WS1`, clicked refactor and renamed the class. However, when running the webservice, the attempt resulted in a server error saying

> Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'MyWS.WS1'.

from which I conclude that there is still a part of my project that thinks the web service is named `WS1`. I found out that the file `TestService.asmx` has remained unchanged, still containing the line

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="TestService.asmx.cs" Class="MyWS.WS1" %>
```

My question is as follows:

Is there a way to rename the webservice in the `.asmx` file through VS's refactoring method? If not, what is the best way to avoid problems like this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS refactoring functionality is usually limited to code *names* (i.e. var name, function name, class name) only, but `MyWS.WS1` in `Class="MyWS.WS1"` is seen by VS as a string *value* which can be anything. The ReSharper plugin has it's own refactor module, that can search for a string references, but again, you will need to manually verify that changes are correct and should be applied.

It's absolutely OK to rename the service manually, just do a solution-wide regular text search for `WS1` to be sure you didn't miss something.

I tested it out, it seems that it only searches code files for .net `string` type strings. So if you have

```
var name = "WS1";
```

it will include it in "strings" search results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but still, on refactoring, I allowed VS to search through strings, and it didn't find the service name in the asmx file. How is it possible that VS doesn't "see" the file?

Comment: Can't really tell, I don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to rename the webservice in the .asmx file through VS's
>   refactoring method?

No, there is no way using standard VS's refactoring method. As @Petr mentioned, standard VS refactoring doesn't care about non-code entries.
**EDIT**: 'non-code entries' means 'entries that are not in your programming language's source files' (.cs, .vb etc).

You need to use more advanced tools like [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper) that do care about all *string* occurrencies of a refactored symbols.

> If not, what is the best way to avoid problems like this?

To avoid problems when not having ReSharper, you need to manually find, analyze and fix all text entries of a symbol you want to rename in all of the solution files.
To accomplish this, you can use **Find in Files** dialog (**Ctrl + Shif + F** if you use standard VS keyboard scheme):

1. Enter the whole symbol text to the **Find what** text box
2. Make sure the **Entire solution** option is selected in the **Look in**
   dropdown
3. Make sure **Match whole word** checkbox is set and **Match case** is NOT
   set
4. Make sure ***.*** is selected in the **Look at these file types** dropdown

After you perform that search, you'll have the full list of occurrences of your symbol in your solution. Perhaps, this list will contain occurrences that isn't related to what you want to do because mentioned search criteria are the weakest possible. But it is up to you to analyze each entry found and to make a decision whether this entry need to be changed or not.
So this approach is the most reliable but also the hardest and slowest.
Of course, in some cases you may use more strict search criteria resulting in the smaller list of symbol entries. For instance, to search in the **Current project** only and with **Match case** option.

Comment: "standard VS refactoring doesn't care about non-code entries." That is not quite true, as VS's rename method does have an option "search in strings", but it seem VS doesn't even see the file `TestService.asmx`

Comment: **Search in strings** option allows to search the symbol in string literals which are located, in this case, in your .cs files, and not in any other file types like .asmx that are in your project\solution. By '**non-code entries**', I meant '**entries that are not in your programming language code files**'.

Comment: I understand now, thank you. I upovted your answer but accepted the one by Petr Abdulin, as it was posted sooner.

Comment: Thank you. I've added explanation about 'non-code entries' to the answer for further readers.